# How do I pass current index to react-image-lightbox?

Tags: reactjs, react-image-lightbox

I am trying to implement a flexible lightbox component for displaying images. I am [using this npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-lightbox) , image URL's i am getting from api.

How should I pass current image index value to (Which image clicked on) the component so that the adject image displayed on modal.

Below is the JSON that I am getting from backend

```
{ 
    "count": 3, 
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/aws/gallery/all-gallery/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        { "id": 127, "gallery_img_url": "https://mysite.amazonaws.com/gallery/test2.jpg" }, 
        { "id": 126, "gallery_img_url": "https://mysite.amazonaws.com/gallery/CaptureXYZ.PNG" }, 
        { "id": 125, "gallery_img_url": "https://mysite.amazonaws.com/gallery/Capture2.PNG" }
    ] 
}
```

onClick image I am passing this id from results array to the component, I think this might be the issue, Can Someone please suggest me how to pass the exact index value (precisely, Image clicked on) to the component.

Here is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllGalleryImages } from '../actions/gallery';
import Lightbox from 'react-image-lightbox';
import 'react-image-lightbox/style.css';



class ViewGalleryImage extends Component {
    state = {
        photoIndex: 0,
        isOpen: false,
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        // this will Fetch data from api

        this.props.getAllGalleryImages();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }
    render() {

        const { photoIndex, isOpen } = this.state;    
        const images = [];    
        this.props.images && this.props.images.results && this.props.images.results.map(result =>
                images.push(result.gallery_img_url),    
        )

        return (

                    <div>
                        {this.props.images.count === 0 ? <p><strong>No Images found!</strong></p> :
                            <React.Fragment>
                                {this.props.images && this.props.images.results && this.props.images.results.map(result =>
                                    <div className='masonry-item' key={result.id}>

                                        <img src={result.gallery_img_url} onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true, photoIndex: result.id })} alt='myImage' className='dlt_blg_img' />
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        }

                        {
                            isOpen && (    
                                <Lightbox

                                    mainSrc={images[photoIndex]}

                                    nextSrc={images[(photoIndex + 1) % images.length]}
                                    prevSrc={images[(photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length]}
                                    onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
                                    onMovePrevRequest={() =>
                                        this.setState({
                                            photoIndex: (photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length,
                                        })
                                    }
                                    onMoveNextRequest={() =>
                                        this.setState({
                                            photoIndex: (photoIndex + 1) % images.length,
                                        })
                                    }
                                />


                            )
                        }



                    </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isLoading: state.gallery.isLoading,
    images: state.gallery

});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getAllGalleryImages }
)(ViewGalleryImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution for this. I think it might help newbie like me.

Below is the part of updated component

```
                <div>
                    {this.props.images.count === 0 ? <p><strong>No Images found!</strong></p> :
                        <React.Fragment>

                    {
                        images.map((index, key) =>
                            <div className='masonry-item' key={key}>

                                <img src={index} alt='gallery' onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true, photoIndex: key })} />
                            </div>
                        )
                    }

                        </React.Fragment>
                    }

                    {
                        isOpen && (    
                            <Lightbox

                                mainSrc={images[photoIndex]}

                                nextSrc={images[(photoIndex + 1) % images.length]}
                                prevSrc={images[(photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length]}
                                onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
                                onMovePrevRequest={() =>
                                    this.setState({
                                        photoIndex: (photoIndex + images.length - 1) % images.length,
                                    })
                                }
                                onMoveNextRequest={() =>
                                    this.setState({
                                        photoIndex: (photoIndex + 1) % images.length,
                                    })
                                }
                            />


                        )
                    }



                </div>
```